# Add element to ul list sorted by time and id

Tags: jquery, socket.io, html-lists

I'm experimenting with [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) which I find absolutely brilliant. I'm trying to build a very simple app that updates a list in real time.

My Node app generates an array with, at least, a unique `id` (non numeric) key and a `time` key which is a unix timestamp per item. What I do now is that I generate a `<li>` element for each item in that array (using [MustacheJS](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)) and push the lot into an existing `<ul>` list in my HTML. So far, so good.

Now, I want to make it a bit better by only pushing new elements, and order them depending on the `time` key, instead of pushing a full list all the time.

What's the best way to do this ?

Here's some dummy code to illustrate my use case :

```
// Let's say this is my initial array
array_one = [
                {
                    id: 'one_1',
                    time: '1467982149',
                    content: 'Content one_1'
                },
                {
                    id: 'one_2',
                    time: '1467983149',
                    content: 'Content one_2'
                },
                {
                    id: 'one_3',
                    time: '1467981149',
                    content: 'Content one_3'
                },
                {
                    id: 'one_4',
                    time: '1467482149',
                    content: 'Content one_4'
                }
            ];

/* 
    Here I take that first array, generate a <li></li> element for
    each item in it, obtaining something like this :

    <li data-id="one_1" data-time="1467982149">Content one_1</li>

    I store all of those in an array, let's say "allMyItems"
*/

/* 
    I have all of my <li> elements, so now I push them to my <ul>
    list using a Socket.IO event and jQuery on the client side.
    It looks like this :

    $('ul').html( 'allMyItems' );
*/

// Later fetch the data again, and there's old but also new elements
// and this is where I don't know how to do it. You can see it's
// mostly the same array but with two new elements
array_one = [
                {
                    id: 'one_1',
                    time: '1467982149',
                    content: 'Content one_1'
                },
                {
                    id: 'one_2',
                    time: '1467983149',
                    content: 'Content one_2'
                },
                {
                    id: 'one_3',
                    time: '1467981149',
                    content: 'Content one_3'
                },
                {
                    id: 'one_4',
                    time: '1467482149',
                    content: 'Content one_4'
                },
                {
                    id: 'two_1',
                    time: '1467432149',
                    content: 'Content two_1'
                },
                {
                    id: 'two_2',
                    time: '1467232149',
                    content: 'Content two_2'
                }
            ];

/* 
    What I want to do now, is :
        1. Update the front-end <ul> list with just the two new items
        2. Correctly sort that <ul> using the 'time' key
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out. It was quite simple, I don't know why it wasn't obvious at first. Here's the logic :

- Server side (Node app), I keep tracks of each IDs sent to the client
- When I have new data, I make sure this ID was not already sent
- I do the sorting client side, directly in the browser (I have settled for the best option yet, but I know it's possible)

Voilà ...